# Como buscar o segundo maior número

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso buscar a foto com o segundo maior salario

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "imagem";

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco."); 

    @mysql_select_db($db) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco"); 

    $img=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arquivo WHERE sal < (SELECT MAX(sal)FROM arquivo)") or die("Impossível executar a query");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($img)) { 
        echo "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->codigo' \">"; 
     }          
?>
```

Comment: a do rray deu certo!! obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode criar duas consulta a mais interna pega os dois maiores registros e ordena do maior para o menor (`DESC`), com isso a consulta mais externa pega o resultado e intervete ele ou seja ordena do menor para o maior (`ASC`) e retorna apenas **uma** das duas linhas.

```
SELECT sal FROM
      (SELECT t.sal FROM cad as t ORDER BY t.sal DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY sal ASC LIMIT 1
```

Adaptando no php ([comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181187/como-buscar-o-segundo-maior-numero#comment374640_181189)) fica:

```
<?php
    $img = mysql_query("SELECT sal FROM (SELECT t.sal FROM cad as t ORDER BY t.sal DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY sal ASC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($img);

    echo !empty($row) ? "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->codigo'>" : '';
```

Comment: porem, só posso exibir na tela o segundo maior salario

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão vc fez um while? pode fazer duas chamadas de `mysql_fetch_asso()` o primeiro vc descarta e o segundo usa.

Comment: nao consegui fzr, te explicar melhor, preciso buscar a foto, que contenha o segundo maior salario.

Comment: <?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "imagem";

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco."); 

    @mysql_select_db($db) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco"); 
    
    $img=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arquivo WHERE sal < (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM arquivo)") or die("Impossível executar a query");
    
     while($row=mysql_fetch_object($img)) { 
     echo "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->codigo' \">"; 
     }    
 ?> nossa ficou muito ruim pra ver, tentei mas n deu tbm

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão editei minha resposta, se precisar retornar mais um campo faça nos dois selects.

Comment: SELECT sal FROM
          (SELECT t.sal FROM cad as t ORDER BY t.sal DESC LIMIT 2)
    ORDER BY sal ASC LIMIT 1

Esse ?

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão isso.

Comment: tentei, mas n chegou exibir nada dessa vez. Coloquei assim: 

$img=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.sal FROM arquivo as t ORDER BY t.sal DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY sal ASC LIMIT 1") or die("Impossível executar a query");

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeSimão editei novamente a resposta.

Comment: ae deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Poderia ser assim:

```
SELECT MAX( SAL ) FROM CAD WHERE SAL < ( SELECT MAX( SAL ) FROM CAD )
```

Comment: possuo muitos registros, assim ele exibiria todos os menores do maior salario.

Comment: Não. Exibe apenas um.

Comment: ele exibiu tods =/

Comment: Hmmmm.. O select puro como está traz apenas um registro, mesmo que haja valores repetidos. Se esta trazendo vários, penso que o problema esteja em outro lugar.

Comment: Se ´SELECT MAX(sal) FROM cad´ traz apenas um, por que ´SELECT MAX( SAL ) FROM CAD WHERE SAL < ( SELECT MAX( SAL ) FROM CAD )´ traria vários?

Comment: Demonstrando a ideia do Reginaldo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/596334/2. Veja que o resultado é 60, o segundo maior, apenas.

Comment: vou fazer outro post la embaixo, com o código como está, de uma conferida .